# CNAME alias from named SQL instance to default instance

Tags: sql-server, alias

I know I can use CNAME alis to point from one SQL Server to another for upgrade or such log shipping, but what if one is named instance and other is default instance?

Do I need SQL alias?

Do i need such like this answer?

[Create an alias for a SQL Server named instance pointing to sql default instance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120306/create-an-alias-for-a-sql-server-named-instance-pointing-to-sql-default-instance)

.thanks

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120360/60085) on the link you provided worked for me.  It should be something that is easily tested.

Comment: The main thing to remember is that the alias needs to be created on the servers that are trying to access the SQL Server instance - not (necessarily) on the server that _hosts_ the SQL Server instance.  Also make sure you address both 32 bit and 64 bit configs.

Comment: You might want to have a look at my Q & A related to [What are valid connection strings for SSMS login box?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/134499/15356). Basically the `<SERVER>\<INSTANCE>` syntax is telling the client to `1.)` connect to the SERVER and then `2.)` Contact the Browswer Service which will redirect the INSTANCE bit to the correct SQL Server instance. If you have configured your instances to listen to dedicated IP addresses and ports, then you could just use a CNAME and no further configuration is required.

Comment: @ScottHodgin ok ty if you want to add an answer or close?

Comment: @hot2use ty will read

Comment: @user172612 - I voted to close your question as it appears to be a duplicate of the post you referenced.