# Impact of changing server machines names with SQL Server 2016 Standard in mirror state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server

It's an enterprise network domain. Two existing Windows server 2016 machines, one each for SQL Server 2016 Standard edition and other is also SQL Server 2016 Standard edition in a passive mirror configuration.

For some reason we need to change both server machine names from say A to B and A1 to B1. Will this have any impact on SQL Server and its passive mirror access? What precautions I need to take? I can understand the connection string with change but I am looking for impact of this change on mirroring configuration particularly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming Windows computer for SQL Server is supported an operation and [described in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). For mirroring, it needs to be turned off and re-established after renaming.  Remember that renaming Windows requires a reboot, so be prepared for service outage.

> When you rename a computer that is configured to use database
>   mirroring, you must turn off database mirroring before the renaming
>   operation. Then, re-establish database mirroring with the new computer
>   name. Metadata for database mirroring will not be updated
>   automatically to reflect the new computer name. Use the following
>   steps to update system metadata.

For what it's worth, could you use SQL [client aliases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120306/4511) instead of renaming the computers?